# Print target labels on xAxis with labels.formatter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I have some `plotLines` and I just need to print `labels` corresponding to those `plotLines` on my `xAxis`.

My data is a random value around 100 (`yAxis`) and dates that increments by 10 days (`xAxis`).

```
var getDaysArray = function(start, end) {
  for (var arr = [], dt = start; dt <= end; dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 10)) {
    arr.push(new Date(dt));
  }
  return arr;
};

function generateDataPoints(noOfDps) {
  var yVal = 100;
  var dps = [];
  var xDate = getDaysArray(new Date("2006-01-01"), new Date("2019-12-30"));
  for (var i = 0; i < xDate.length; i++) {
    yVal = yVal + Math.round(5 + Math.random() * (-5 - 5));
    dps.push({ x: xDate[i], y: yVal });
  }
  return dps;
}

let dataPoints = generateDataPoints(100);
```

There is also a function that gets the min, max, first and last values of `y` and returns an array of `markers`. Those are the points where I have `plotLines`.

```
function setHighestLowest(dtPoints) {
  let highestIndex = -1;
  let minimumIndex = -1;
  let highestValue = 0;
  let lowestValue = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < dtPoints.length; i++) {
    let obj = dtPoints[i];
    if (obj.y > highestValue) {
      highestIndex = i;
      highestValue = obj.y;
    }
    if (obj.y < lowestValue || i === 0) {
      minimumIndex = i;
      lowestValue = obj.y;
    }
  }

  dtPoints[0].indexLabel = dtPoints[0].y.toString();
  dtPoints[dtPoints.length - 1].indexLabel = dtPoints[
    dtPoints.length - 1
  ].y.toString();
  if (highestIndex > -1) {
    dtPoints[highestIndex].indexLabel = dtPoints[highestIndex].y.toString();
  }
  if (minimumIndex > -1) {
    dtPoints[minimumIndex].indexLabel = dtPoints[minimumIndex].y.toString();
  }
  //returns -> [max[0], min[1], first[2], last[3]]
  let dateMarker = [
    dtPoints[highestIndex].x,
    dtPoints[minimumIndex].x,
    dtPoints[1].x,
    dtPoints[dtPoints.length - 1].x
  ];
  //console.log(dateMarker);
  return dateMarker;
}
```

My approach is to define `labels.formatter` functions for the `xAxis`.

First issue I found was the increment steps, I tried `xAxis.labels.step` but it didn't work, than I found `xAxis.tickIntervals` it seemed to work at first, the only problem was that to prevent labels from being printed outside of `xAxis` area the formatter function value started from a previous point from my dataset, there was some kind of offset, `formatter` function increment would never fit my data (offset problem). To solve this offset problem I tried the `xAxis.tickPositions` and called my markers array, from that point I was able to acces the points on `formatter` function, the only problem is that it returns nothing, I get inside the `if` loop that does the checking but nothing is printed on `xAxis.labels`.

The final result I want in my plot is something like that:

[image]

This is my code:

[image: Edit Highcharts React xAxis Label Formatter]

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about use the **plotLines.label** feature to render those labels? I think that it will be easier to implement this logic there.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-xaxis-label-formatter-8xdcg

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines.label